# Failed to connect to PostgreSQL server due to changing the port number during installation

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, port

I changed the initial port number for PostgreSQL during installation. I thereafter tried to connect to the server, but failed. The `postgresql.conf` file still shows that I'm connected to port `5432`, but the error below keeps popping up.

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and acceptingTCP/IP connections on port 5500?
```

I have tried to clear the `Appdata` but even after reinstalling with port `5432`, I still haven't managed to connect to the server.

Comment: If `postgresql.conf` contains `port=5432` **and no other `port` line**, `postgresql.auto.conf` is empty, PostgreSQL is started without the `-p` option, and if there is no other file `postgresql.conf` on the machine, and you stop and start PostgreSQL, this cannot happen. So check these things.